# Does Totem apply Replaygain?

Tags: mp3, totem, gstreamer, replaygain

I'm trying to use replaygain to change the volume of some MP3 files, but although I seem to have changed the file successfully (I used easymp3gain-gtk and mp3gain, and I checked the file with mp3gain -s c), Totem does not play the files with any difference in volume. I know Totem uses gstreamer, but I don't know how to check if Totem has recognised and is applying the replaygain.

How can I check if Totem is correctly reading and applying the replaygain? Are there totem or gstreamer commands that allow me to check?

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly say, GStreamer does support replaygain. However I don't think it is enabled unless an application specifically requests it.

I'd advise testing your files in Rhythmbox or Banshee (both of which have a preference to turn replaygain on).

Comment: This is correct.  Applications need to explicitly link an _rgvolume_ element into their GStreamer pipeline.